# How to remove automatically data backup from iCloud in ios app

Tags: ios

My app goes rejected from app store due to iCloud back up limit while i am not saving any data to iCloud. Please help me.

Comment: Wouldn't this be something that the app store support could help you out with?

Comment: Please make in your next question clear that you are using Cordova.

Answer (score 1):

But presumable you are saving some data in the documents directory. Apple says that you have to mark this data that it is not backed up by iCloud. [This might help.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html) (But this should also be in the answer you got from Apple.

Answer (score 1):

By default, any data stored in an app's Documents directory is backed up to iCloud. Apple's iOS data storage guidelines (found [here](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/)) specify that any data which can be recreated by the user must NOT be backed up to iCloud.

You have a couple of options here

1. Save the data to `<Application_Home>/Library/Caches` or `<Application_Home>/tmp` depending on your use case
2. Mark the files you are saving in Documents directory with a "do not backup" flag (as explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html))

Answer (score 1):

To apply attributes to all files :)) ( of course you may exclude needed)

In

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Add this.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

[self applyAttributes:documentsDirectory];    

paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

[self applyAttributes:documentsDirectory];


paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

[self applyAttributes:documentsDirectory];



-(void)applyAttributes:(NSString *)folderPath
{
  NSArray *filesArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:folderPath error:nil];
  NSEnumerator *filesEnumerator = [filesArray objectEnumerator];
  NSString *fileName;

  while (fileName = [filesEnumerator nextObject]) {

    if([self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]]])
    {
        //NSLog(@"success applying");
    }


}

}



- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
  if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]])
  {
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                                  forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
    if(!success){
        NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
    }
    return success;
}

return NO;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your Cordova.plist file.  In backup Storage change to cloud = none.
Take help from reference in cordova framework.
This won't work for native Applications.  For a native app, the developer notify or Authentication  to user that app will be make storage on iCloud.